# error adding golang cobra package with glide

Tags: go, go-cobra

My glide.yaml import section is

```
import:
  - package: github.com/spf13/cobra
```

I have

```
import (
   "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)
```

in my code.

but I am getting the error

> vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:1092: c.lflags.SortFlags undefined (type *pflag.FlagSet has no field or method SortFlags)
>   vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:1092: c.Flags().SortFlags undefined (type *pflag.FlagSet has no field or method SortFlags)
>   vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:1240: c.parentsPflags.SortFlags undefined (type *pflag.FlagSet has no field or method SortFlags)

couples of issues on cobra repo says that can happen if pflag package is old version but in my case don't have that package installed separately.
any idea what am I doing wrong? thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try installing the pflag package? I'm guessing you do have it installed, and don't realize it, otherwise you'd get a different error.

Comment: Did you actually run `glide`? Or did you just put it in the `glide.yaml`? Usually, glide should take care of the dependencies for you.

Comment: @Flimzy pflag package is automatically installed and is present in my vendor dir. ls on ./vendor/github.com/spf13/ gives output
cobra  pflag

Comment: @Carpetsmoker obviously I did a glide install :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was problem with glide cache not updating why old version of pflag package was getting installed. More detailed info: https://github.com/spf13/cobra/issues/420